# How to run a job on specific times every day from Monday to Friday in Rundeck?

Tags: job-scheduling, rundeck

Is there any way to run the job every day from Monday to Friday at 45 mins time interval from 2.45 pm to 5 pm. (The job should run at 2.45pm , 3.30pm, 4.15, 5.00). Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways:

One way is to create four jobs scheduled at a single time every Mon-Fri.  Give each a single step, which is a job reference to the real job.  For example, the first job would be scheduled to run at 2.45pm every Mon-Fri, the second at 3.30pm, etc.  You're not making copies of the existing job, just single-step jobs that reference the original.

That approach lets you manage each scheduled time individually.

Another way is to schedule it every 15 minutes from 2.00pm to 5.45pm, and add an initial step that fails if the time is before 2.45pm or after 5.01pm.  If you don't want to see these failures, you could add an error step to that first step which marks the job succeeded even if it's really skipping all the real steps.

Paul M. Lambert
Platform Solutions Architect
Rundeck, Inc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am planning to follow the first way. But could please you please share some example xml for the the second way (particularly to add the initial step if the time before 2.45pm or 5.01pm. Also to skip the failures by adding error step to that first step)